# How to connect 3 cell series Li ion charger and protection IC for each cell?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, protection, lipo

I am using [max745](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX745.pdf) 4 cell Li-ion battery charger to charge 3 cells in series.
I want to put additional protection IC for each cell (NCR18650pf). Because I need to run the max745 always on as a backup rechargeable pack.

I am going to use 
[AP9101CK6](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP9101C.pdf)-AETRG1DICT. (protection - OV/UV/OC/short circuit)

AP9101C have P+ and P- pin.
In my case, I have 3cells in series,
If I connect AP9101CK6 IC per cell (each cell have one AP9101CK6 IC)
Is follow configuration correct?

1st cell (1st AP9101 IC) P+ --> BATT pin of max745

1st cell (1st AP9101 IC) P- --> 2nd cell (2nd AP9101 IC)P +

2nd cell (2nd AP9101 IC) P- --> 3rd  cell(3rd AP9101 IC) P+

3rd cell (3rd AP9101 IC) P- --> GND of max745

same time AP9101C P- the pin is connected to common GND as shown in the circuit
will this become a short circuit?

[image: AP9101C]

[image: max745]

Comment: Notice that the AP9101C is designed for a single-cell battery pack.

Comment: @Nick Alexeev so AP9101C can be used only for  3.7V 1x cell battery? cant i use this IC for each cell (3 ICs total )and connect them in series?